# How to get UIBarButtonItem to open a new view controller?

Tags: iphone

I want to add method that opens up the new view controller when this info button is pressed.

```
  UIBarButtonItem *infoItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                          initWithTitle:@"Info" 
                          style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                          target:nil 
                          action:@selector(action)];
```

Comment: Inside the action selector you can write your own code to push the views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)action {
   MyViewController *myView = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
   [myView presentModalViewController:YES]; // present view modally
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:myView animated:YES]; // add to navigation stack
   [myView release];
}
```